# How to run sprite animation when click the button in unity 3d

Tags: c#, sprite, unity-game-engine

I am doing one mini game in unity 3d,in which I have door animation, I created door sprite in inspector,Now my question is when i click that door that needs to open,and I used object Instantiate method,[players = (GameObject) Instantiate(playerPrefab, new_size, Quaternion.identity);] but I think this is not a suitable method to do because it create dublicate copy of door that is why,if there are any other idea please reply

Comment: Please state what type of gameObject you are using to display the sprite.
GUItexture? External library? Some other method?

Comment: Unless there's been significant additions to Unity's API that adds a class named Sprite, I don't think that's what you're using. You might want to check what components are attached to this gameObject that enable it to render what you call a sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the texture stored as a variable in you class. Then you shall call  a method(For example a IEnumerator or you can use a if statement in Update()) Then insert the code from [SPrite Animation from wiki.unity3d.com](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=Animating_Tiled_texture_-_Extended) into your Class(class.cs).

or you can insert an if statement into the Update Method in the [Sprite Animation](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=Animating_Tiled_texture_-_Extended) and turn it to true when you want to call the animation.